# Apache camel - ending transaction for posting to queue for secondary processing

Tags: apache-camel, spring-transactions

Below is my route

```
from('direct-vm:parentconsumer)
.transacted(PROPAGATION_POLICY)
.process()
.to(jms:queueName)
```

Would like to end transaction before sending to jms queue. Could someone help how to end transaction after .process in spring DSL

Comment: use wiretap eip

Comment: But only after commiting the transaction the jms queue can retrieve updated data and process hence the transaction is to be commited.

Comment: split into a separate route for the transaction and then call this route first, and then the send afterwards.